# jQuery alert box not working

Tags: jquery

I have a tiny bit of code thats meant to show a javascript alert when a select list is changed value, but it doesnt seem to be working, could anyone give me a hand and let me know where im going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sources").change(function(e) {
        alert('This is what an alert message looks like.');
    });
});
```

HTML for the select is as follows:

```
<select name="sources" id="sources" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">please select</option>
  <option value="5">Seek</option>
  <option value="6">friends</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you also post the HTML for `sources`?

Comment: what kind of element is `#sources` ?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vqLUe/

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/L45sf/
Are you including jQuery correctly, or receiving any sort of errors from other conflicting javascript?

Comment: Ohhh, i think i see whats going on ... jQuery is being used to generate the dropdown list on the fly ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your last comment, if jQuery is being used to generate the dropdown list on the fly, you need to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to bind your dropdown:

```
$('#sources').live('change', function(e) { //do stuff });
```

Comment: Oww this is what i need ... so i just replace $("#sources").change(function(e) { with what you wrote?